# My media queries and flexbox isnt working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

So, I've done the mistake of coding for a desktop website first, rather than the mobile version. Now, im using the media query of (max-width: 576px) and tried to design my header / navbar, but it doesn't seem to work. It also goes out of my header tag and makes the whole website make a dark space to the right.

[The DAMN logo is supposed to be over the 3 links, who are supposed to be evenly spaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZMO.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSJER.png).

[image: The logo goes out of the width i want, which makes the whole document a bit larger along the x-axis]

Wanted the DAMN logo on top, and then the 3 links aligned under in a space-evenly format with flex

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DotGothic16&family=Roboto:wght@500;700&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap');
    
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-right: none;
        width: 100%;
        
        /* height: 165rem; */
        
        
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 20px;
      }
      
      /* Track */
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
       
      /* Handle */
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: red; 
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      
      /* Handle on hover */
      ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #b30000; 
      }
    /* Header */
    
    
    
    header {
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 6rem;
      border-bottom: none;
      position: sticky;
    top: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
      border-radius: 15px;
     
    }
    
    
    
    #navBar2 {
      margin-right: 10rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 500px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: red;
      font-family:"DotGothic16", sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: bold;
    } 
    
    #onThisPage{
      color: gray;
      cursor: default
    }
    
    #onThisPage:after {
      border-radius: 1em;
      border-top: .1em solid red;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
        right: 100%;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
      transition: right 1s cubic-bezier(0,.5,1,1);
    }
    
    
    
    #logo {
      width: 10rem;
      margin-left: 8rem;
    }
    
    
    /* Hentet fra nettet */
    
    
    .navLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .navLink:after {
      border-radius: 1em;
      border-top: .1em solid red;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
        right: 100%;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
      transition: right 1s cubic-bezier(0,.5,1,1);
    }
    
    .navLink:hover:after {
      right: 0;
    }
    
    /* FIRST ALBUM */
    #firstAlbum {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    img:not(#logo) {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      box-shadow: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 10px 10px,
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3) 15px 15px,
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) 20px 20px,
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 25px 25px, 
       rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05) 30px 30px;
       transition: 1s;
    }
    
    
    
    #secondAlbum {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10rem;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    #thirdAlbum {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10rem;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    #fourthAlbum{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      margin-top: 10rem;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    :root {
      --primary: white;
      --secondary: #192824;
      --background: black;
      --green: red;
      --yellow: white;
      --orange: red;
      --red: white;
    } 
    
    .card {
      background-color: var(--background);
      width: 500px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 15px 20px ;
      margin-top: 80px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      border: 3px solid var(--primary);
      box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--green),
            20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--yellow),
            30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--orange),
            40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--red);
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      animation: shadow-wave 3s ease infinite;
      transform: scale(1.2);
      transition: 1s
    }
    
    
    @keyframes shadow-wave {
      0% {
        border: 3px solid var(--primary);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--green),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--yellow),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--orange),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--red);
      }
      20% {
        border: 3px solid var(--red);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--primary),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--green),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--yellow),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--orange);
      }
      40% {
        border: 3px solid var(--orange);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--red),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--primary),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--green),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--yellow);
      }
      60% {
        border: 3px solid var(--yellow);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--orange),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--red),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--primary),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--green);
      }
      80% {
        border: 3px solid var(--green);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--yellow),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--orange),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--red),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--primary);
      }
      100% {
        border: 3px solid var(--primary);
        box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 -3px var(--background), 10px -10px var(--green),
          20px -20px 0 -3px var(--background), 20px -20px var(--yellow),
          30px -30px 0 -3px var(--background), 30px -30px var(--orange),
          40px -40px 0 -3px var(--background), 40px -40px var(--red);
      }
      
    }
    
    .card p {
      font-size: 21px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: "DotGothic16", sans-serif;
      
    }
    
    .card h2 {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: "Roboto";
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .list {
      margin-top: 20px;
      color: gray;
      padding: 5px 0;
      font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    button {
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #pageNum {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
      font-family: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family:"DotGothic16", sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      
      
    }
    
    #pageNav {
      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 100px;
      transition: 1s;
    }
    
    #next > a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #next {
      
      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }
    
    #next::after {
      content: "";
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 50px;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }
    
    #next:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
      transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #next:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    
    #footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 40px
    }
    
    footer {
      border-top: 1px solid white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 200px;
      padding: 100px
    }
    
    #footerLogo {
      transform: scale(2);
      position: relative;
      right: 100px;
    }
    
    
    #contact, #kendrickInfo > h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    
    
    
    #info {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 50px;
      
    }
    
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
      
    }
    
    ul > h1 {
      font-family: "DotGothic16";
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    
    .footerLink {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      text-decoration: none;
      width: fit-content;
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    
    
    .footerLink:after {
      border-radius: 1em;
      border-top: .1em solid red;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
        right: 100%;
        top: 20px;
        left: 0;
      transition: right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1,.5,1,1);
    }
    
    .footerLink:hover{
      color: white;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .footerLink:hover:after {
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      
    
    <div id = "content">
    
        <header class = "sticky">
    
            <div id = "logoDiv">
                <a id = "home" href = "homepage.html">
                    <img id = "logo" src = "/kendrick_imgs/logo_k.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div id ="navBar">
                <a class = "navLink" href = "">ACHIEVEMENTS</a>
                <a class = "navLink" href = "/Website/History/history.html">HISTORY</a>
                <a class = "navLink" href = "/Website/Album/page1.html">ALBUMS</a>
            </div>
    
        </header>
    
        <main>
    
        <div id = "kendrickIntro">
            <div id = "imgText" data-aos="fade-right">
                A poet with his words. A magician with his flow. An artist of the people, from the people, for the people
            </div>
            <div id = "bg-img">
                <img  data-aos = "fade-left" id = "kendrickImg" src = "/kendrick_imgs/kendrickImg.jpg" alt = "Kendrick Lamar on stage">
            </div>
           
        </div>
    
        <div id = "albumShowcase">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "mrMorale" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/Mr.morale.webp">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "damn" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/DAMN.jpg">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "untitled" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/Untitled Unmastered.jpg">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "pimpAButterfly" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/toPimpAButterfly.png">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "maadCity" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/m.A.A.d city.jpg">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "section80" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/Section.80.jpg">
            <img data-aos = "fade-in" id = "dedicated" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/OverlyDedicated.webp">
            <img  id = "c4" class = "album" src = "/album_imgs/C4.jpg" data-aos = "fade-in" >
    </div>
    
    
        </main>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <footer data-aos = "fade-up">
    
            <div id = "footerLogo">
                <a id = "home" href = "homepage.html">
                    <img id = "logo" src = "/kendrick_imgs/logo_k.png"></a>
            </div>
    
            <div id = "info">
                <ul id = "contact">
                    <h1>me.</h1>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://www.instagram.com/moadbouzidi_/">Instagram</a>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://github.com/0xMoad">Github</a>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://www.facebook.com/moad.bouzidi.16/">Facebook</a>
                </ul>
    
                <ul id = "kendrickInfo">
                    <h1>kendrick.</h1>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://www.instagram.com/kendricklamar/">Instagram</a>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3lBXcrKFnFAFkfVk5WuKcQ">Youtube</a>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2YZyLoL8N0Wb9xBt1NhZWg">Spotify</a>
                    <a class = "footerLink" href = "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/kendrick-lamar/368183298">iTunes </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
        </footer>
    
        <div id="loader">
            <img src = "/kendrick_imgs/loader.gif">
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
        <script>
          AOS.init();
        </script>
        <script src = "/Website/Hjem/loader.js"></script>
     
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correct then you could change the flex direction like

```
   header {
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column; <--
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 6rem;
      border-bottom: none;
      position: sticky;
    top: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
      border-radius: 15px;
     
    }
```

Comment: still the same :(